# I can create an entity, but I can't edit one

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Here's my controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ProductViewModel viewModel)
{
    Product product = _ProductsRepository.GetProduct(viewModel.ProductId);
    TryUpdateModel(product);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _productsRepository.SaveProduct(product);
        TempData["message"] = product.Name + " has been saved.";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(viewModel);     // validation error, so redisplay same view
}



[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CommodityCategoryViewModel viewModel)
{
    Product product = new Product();
    TryUpdateModel(product);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _productsRepository.SaveProduct(product);
        TempData["message"] = product.Name + " has been saved.";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(viewModel);     // validation error, so redisplay same view
}
```

They both call a Save() function, defined here:

```
public class ProductsRepository
{
    private readonly MyDBEntities _entities;

    public ProductsRepository()
    {            
        _entities = new MyDBEntities();
    }

    public void SaveProduct(Product product)
    {
        // If it's a new product, just attach it to the DataContext
        if (product.ProductID == 0)
            _entities.Products.Context.AddObject("Products", product);
        else if (product.EntityState == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            // We're updating an existing product, but it's not attached to this data context, so attach it and detect the changes
            _entities.Products.Context.Attach(product);
            _entities.Products.Context.Refresh(System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.ClientWins, product);
        }
        _entities.Products.Context.SaveChanges();  // Edit function hits here
    }
}
```

When I call Create, it hits AddObject() in the SaveProduct() function, and saves the product correctly.

When I call Edit, it only hits _entities.Products.Context.SaveChanges() in the SaveProduct() function, and the product isn't saved.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not use _entities.SaveChanges(); instead? And you'd better to use this pattern: using(var context = new MyDBEntities()){...} for data access.

Comment: your product object may not be in Modified state since your view model(ProductViewModel) is different from your entity(Product). Try inspecting the changed entities `context.ChangeTracker.Entries()`

Comment: @Eranga - the EntityState is Modified. What change to my code do I need to make?

Comment: does MyDBEntities inherit from DbContext or ObjectContext? try `_entities.SaveChanges()` check whether you are not using the same context for `GetProduct` and `SaveProduct` :)

Comment: Is the product saved in the same context used to saving the product? How do you check that product is not saved?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
// We're updating an existing product, but it's not attached to this data context, so attach it and detect the changes            
_entities.Products.Context.Attach(product);            
_entities.Products.Context.Refresh(System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.ClientWins, product);
```

try:

```
Product origProduct =_entities.Products.Where(m=>m.ProductId == product.ProductId).Single();
_entities.Products.Attach(product, origProduct);
```

This loads in the original object that is attached and gives it the new values. ProductId was a guess.... It will be whatever your key is.